# Is SELinux really useful or needed

Tags: arch-linux, selinux, boot

So I noticed that Fedora takes around 35 seconds to boot and ArchBang was only taking around 15. I did soom looking into it and I guess SELinux has a lot to dow ith this and I was wondering if ArchBang has SELinux...

How are systems secure if they don't have SELinux? Should I, as a home user, worry?

Comment: I doubt SELinux slows it down so much. Set `SELINUX=disabled` in `/etc/selinux/config` and see for yourself. The current policy covers mostly (network facing) services and just a few desktop applications like Wine. Though keep in mind that some of the services are used by desktop users too, e.g. NetworkManager, chrony, rngd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with any other security related question, it depends a lot on factors like the environment where your computer is, the kind of information you store on it, etc. But as a general rule I don't think SELinux is worthy for a home computer.